# Netbeans different return values

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

Working on a java homework project and ran into a little problem. When I compile and run the app in eclipse, I get the expected results. However, when I run it in Netbeans, I get a different result. The issue arises when I check the value of inputFile.hasNext(). On eclipse it returns true, the result expected, but on Netbeans the call returns false. Any idea what would cause this issues ? How do i fix it ? The problem is occurring at while(inputFIle.hasNext()).

```
public int charCountHelper(File handle, Character x) throws IOException {
    int count = 0;
    String data;
    int index;
    Character[] contents;
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(handle);
    while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
        data = inputFile.nextLine();
        index = data.length() - 1;
        contents = new Character[data.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            contents[i] = data.charAt(i);

        }
        count += charCount(contents, x, index);
    }
    return count;
}
```

This is the recursive method that is being called.

```
public int charCount(Character[] content, Character x, int index) {


    if(index < 0){
        return 0; // this value represents the character count if the program reaches the beginning of the array and has not found a match.
    }
    if (content[index].equals(x)) {
        return 1 + charCount(content, x, index - 1);
    }
        return charCount(content, x, index - 1); // this is the value that gets returned to the charCountHelper method.

}
```

This is the main method for the class.

```
    private void Run() throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = null;
        Character letter;
        File handle;
        Integer selection;
        boolean isNumber;
                String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
                System.out.println(path);

            do{
            System.out.println("Enter the number for the type of file to be read.");
            System.out.println("Press 1 to read from a file.");
            System.out.println("Press 2 to read from a file with no entries.");
            System.out.println("Press 3 to read from a file with excessive entries.");
            System.out.println("Press 0 to exit from the program.");

//This "if" statement is used for data type checking to makes sure that the user is entering valid data.
// if invalid data is entered, the "else" statement presents the user with the problem and then recycles the loop until valid data is entered.
            if(input.hasNextInt()){
                selection = input.nextInt();
                isNumber = true;

// This "if" statement manages the type of file to read from.               
                if(selection == 0){
                    System.out.println("Program exited.");
                    System.exit(0);
                    }
                    else if(selection == 1){
                        fileName = path+"/data.txt";
                        break;
                    }else if(selection == 2){
                        fileName = path+"/data2.txt";
                        break;
                    }else if(selection == 3){
                        fileName = path+"/data3.txt";
                        break;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Invalid input.");
                        System.out.println("Valid inputs are numers 0 - 3. Please try again.");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        isNumber = false;
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Invalid input.");
                    System.out.println("Valid input are the numbers 0 - 3, Please try again.");
                    isNumber = false;
                    input.next();
                }

        }while(!(isNumber));

        handle = new File(fileName); // file handle is created using the previous loop to determine which file to read from.
        System.out.println("Enter a character to check.");
        letter = (char) System.in.read();
        input.close();// closes the open Scanner(good house keeping).

        System.out.println("There are "+charCountHelper(handle,letter)+" "+letter+"\'s");

    }
```

Comment: Code formatted so that it is now readable. In the future, please do this for us. Note that the answer to this will depend completely on the contents of your input file and on your charCount method.

Comment: The input file is a plain text file. The charCount method is a recursive method that calculates the amount of times that a particular character appears in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the issue you report seems to be with the IDE, I would suggest the problem may be with the path of the file that is being passed as a parameter. Is NetBeans even recognizing the file?

In Eclipse, the current relative path is set to the project directory. The following code snippet will explain this better.

```
Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
String myPath = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
System.out.println("Current relative path is: " + myPath);
```

I speculate that the paths may be an issue here. Maybe we can understand better, if you post some information about that.

Comment: The 3 data files, data.txt. data2.txt, and data3.txt are each in the project folder of both ide's. I am able to access the data files from a previous method in both ide's its just when that particular call is made in netbeans, it returns false.

Comment: The path stated in netbeans is Current relative path is: E:\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\AlphaCount

Comment: Can you report if closing the scanner by calling the close() method, after your previous access solves the issue? I am struggling to find an explanation for this behavior.

Comment: input.close(); is being called in the previous method already.